# query for pagination for mssql database return an error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pagination

I m try create query for pagination

this is the query.

```
SELECT * FROM
 ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TEST].[dbo].[Registration]. 
 [RegistrationNo] as row 
 FROM [TEST].[dbo].[Registration] ) a 
WHERE row > 5 and row <= 10
```

when i try to run this query on microsoft sql server studio, it return an error saying that

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

- TEST was database name
- dbo.Registration is table name
- dbo.Registration.RegistrationNo is Primary key Column for table
  dbo.Registration

is this information enough to detect the problem?, or should i provide query for create Registration table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing `)` after order by

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TEST].[dbo].[Registration].[RegistrationNo]) as row 
FROM [TEST].[dbo].[Registration] ) a 
WHERE row > 5 and row <= 10
```

Comment: @stacheldraht27 : Great. mark it as answer if it answers your quesiton.